# Optimizing paint code

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to optimize the following code:

```
    private void Screen_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics bmpGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(_screenBitmap);

        int xLoc = 0;
        int yLoc = 0;

        bmpGraphics.Clear(Color.Black);
        _resetInvoked = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i += 2)
        {
            var bgBit = (byte) ((_screenMemory[i + 1]) & 112);
            var fgBit = (byte)((_screenMemory[i + 1]) & 15);
            SolidBrush bgBrush = _backgroundBrushesArray[bgBit/16];
            SolidBrush fgBrush = _foregroundBrushesArray[fgBit];

            if (((xLoc % 640) == 0) && (xLoc != 0))
            {
                yLoc += 12;
                xLoc = 0;
            }
            if (_resetInvoked)
            {
                string s = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_screenMemory, i, 1);
                var pf = new PointF(xLoc, yLoc);

                bmpGraphics.FillRectangle(bgBrush, xLoc + 2, yLoc + 3, 8f, 11f);
                bmpGraphics.DrawString(s, _renderFont, fgBrush, pf);

            }
            xLoc += 8;
        }

        _resetInvoked = false;

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(_screenBitmap, new Point(0, 0));
        bmpGraphics.Dispose();
    }
```

This is a Winforms User Control that mimics a console like screen. Its working just fine, but I'd like to speed it up. Running it through Telerik's JustCode performance monitor, the slowest performance seems to come from the `FillRectangle` and `DrawString` methods. Is there anyway to speed this up?

Comment: Why do you set `_resetInvoked` to true in the beginning and then set to false, and why is `if (_resetInvoked)` in there if it's always true?

Comment: @janos -- I only copied in the relevant code. But I have it in there because my application is multithreaded and I `_resetInvoked` is a flag used to determine, basicially, if the `Paint` event is currently already "painting". I didn't want the `Paint` event to execute if there is already a painting going on.

Comment: `_resetInvoked` is a strange name for that, unless it is only set during reset events. I would recommend something more like `_busy` since that's what you seem to be using it for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Magic numbers**

You have a lot of magic numbers in your code. Consider to express them as meaningful constants. ( 4000, 112, 15, 16, 640, 12, 8f, 11f)

**Style**

Be consistent with your coding style.

> ```
> string s = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_screenMemory, i, 1);
> var pf = new PointF(xLoc, yLoc);
> ```

at the first line you explicitly declare `s` as `string`  also it is quite obvious by the right hand side that it is a string. On the second line you use var as expected.

There is nothing wrong with declaring implict by using the type, but here you should have either used var also or instead of var `PointF`.

**Naming**

Use meaningful names for variables. **Mr.Maintainer** will thank you for doing so. `s` and `pf` are poor names.

**Using statement**

Instead of creating and disposing the `Graphics` you should enclose this inside a using statement, so in case of an exception the `Graphics` object is properly disposed.

**Declaring variables**

Variables should be declared as nearly as possible of their use ( here: the brushes ).

**Refactoring**

This won't do anything regarding speed, if the bottleneck are the `FillRectangle()` and `DrawString()` methods.

There is no sense in entering the loop or doing anything if `_resetInvoked==true`. So using a guard condition to return early is the way to go.

```
private void Screen_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{

    if (_resetInvoked) { return; }  
    _resetInvoked = true;

    using (Graphics bmpGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(_screenBitmap))
    {

        int xLoc = 0;
        int yLoc = 0;

        bmpGraphics.Clear(Color.Black);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i += 2)
        {

            if (((xLoc % 640) == 0) && (xLoc != 0))
            {
                yLoc += 12;
                xLoc = 0;
            }

            var bgBit = (byte) ((_screenMemory[i + 1]) & 112);
            SolidBrush bgBrush = _backgroundBrushesArray[bgBit/16];
            bmpGraphics.FillRectangle(bgBrush, xLoc + 2, yLoc + 3, 8f, 11f);

            var fgBit = (byte)((_screenMemory[i + 1]) & 15);
            SolidBrush fgBrush = _foregroundBrushesArray[fgBit];

            var currentText = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_screenMemory, i, 1);
            var currentPoint = new PointF(xLoc, yLoc);
            bmpGraphics.DrawString(currentText, _renderFont, fgBrush, currentPoint);

            xLoc += 8;
        }

    }

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(_screenBitmap, new Point(0, 0));
    _resetInvoked = false;
}
```

Comment: The default constructor for Point will create you a point at 0,0. There is no need to specify it. Otherwise, great answer as usual.